# does the client instance from microsoft-graph-client refreshes the token itself?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm claiming an access token by using the `acquireTokenWithClientCredentials` function from the **adal-node** package.

After that I use the **@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client** package to create a client instance consuming the Graph API.

```
private client: Client;

async getClient(): Promise<Client> {
    if (!this.client) {
        const accessToken: string = /* get access token from adal-node */;

        this.client = Client.init({
            authProvider: (done) => {
                done(null, accessToken);
            },
        });
    }

    return this.client;
}
```

The client itself only ships with an `api` function. I would like to know if the client takes care for the access token expiration or if I have to care for it.

So before making a call I could do `token.expiresOn < new Date()` to check if a token has expired. If true, I could create a new client instance. But I would like to know if I have to or if I just have to initialize the client once and everything will be fine "forever".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unnecessary to handle access token expiration by yourself.

Each time you need to use access token, just call `acquireTokenWithClientCredentials`.

If the token has not expired, it will still return you the old token.

If it expires, it will get a new one instead.

Comment: thanks for your reply. So the client will do some magic in the background the refresh the token?

Comment: @Question3r. To be precise, it does not refresh the token, but obtains a new token. They are app tokens, and they don't require the user to be online. Just run the same request again once the first token is expired and you'll get a new one.